# Remove iframe after popup close Jquery mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I created simple jquery mobile website, where you click an button and iframe with video is loaded on popup.

My problem is that video keeps playing after i close the popup.

**How can i avoid this?**

Jquery mobile documentation says that this will happen, and i should listen to **popupafterclose** event. 
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/popup-iframes.html

But how can i do that, can someone make me an example?

Demo of problem: http://jsfiddle.net/43nk572m/1/

HTML:

```
<!-- BUTTONS -->
  <a href="#testing" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="fade" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-info">Open Iframe Popup1</a>
  <a href="#testing2" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="fade" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-info">Open Iframe Popup2</a>

<!--POPUPS-->
<div data-role="popup" id="testing" data-theme="b" data-tolerance="15,15">
  <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a>
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>blablabla</h1>
  </div>
  <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/110823244" width="520" height="360" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless"></iframe>
</div>
<div data-role="popup" id="testing2" data-theme="b" data-tolerance="15,15">
  <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a>
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>blablabla</h1>
  </div>
  <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/110823244" width="520" height="360" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless"></iframe>
</div>
```

Please note that popup div id is always changing so i cant just call some javascript to kill #testing2 for example.

I appriciate your help!
Regards
M

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like this:

```
$("#testing").bind({
   popupafterclose: function(event, ui) {
     $(this).find('iframe').remove();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the popup div, you can use the jQuery selector `'[data-role="popup"]'`. To catch the popupafterclose event, delegate it from the document, so that any dynamically created popups will trigger the event:

```
$(document).on( "popupafterclose", '[data-role="popup"]',  function( event, ui ) {
    $(this).find("iframe").prop("src", "");
});
```

In the event handler, find the iframe element and set its src prop to an empty string.

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/43nk572m/4/)**

Comment: it only works on the first click, on the second one the iframe src is empty, useless.

Comment: @PedroLobito, that's what the OP wanted, as he/she is creating the popups dynamically.  You can set the src to the URL when you open the popup in several ways, it depends how your site is setup...